# How to convert date to local date as per the timezone in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have there columns in one table : date, local_date, timezone. The records like:

```
date        local_date    timezone
2017-04-14  2017-04-14    EST
2017-06-04  2017-06-03    CST
2017-06-04  2017-06-03    AST
```

I was trying to use `TO_CHAR(CAST(CAST(source_dt AS TIMESTAMP) AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE )) AS LOCAL_DATE`, but as the timezone is different for each record, the function didn't work.

Comment: what exactly is your desired output?

Comment: Did you try `CAST(source_dt AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) at time zone "TIMEZONE"` https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG265

Comment: The whole idea is meaningless. A specific date-time (timestamp) can be converted from one time zone to another. A "date" does not have a time zone, so converting a date from one time zone to another makes no sense. When it is June 6 in the U.S., it may be June 6 in Europe, or June 7. Which one will you pick? **Or**: Do you mean the "date" column is an Oracle `date` data type, and you are only showing the date portion, but it has a time-of-day component? And same for `local_date`?

Comment: Or is local_date supposed to be a calculated field based on date and timezone?

Comment: What is **EST**, **CST** and **AST**? Check `SELECT TZNAME, TZABBREV, TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME) FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES WHERE TZNAME IN ('EST','CST','AST') OR TZABBREV IN ('EST','CST','AST');`

Comment: Hello All, my question might be not clear. The purpose for this function is to convert "date" to "local_date" base on the value of "timezone".I am verify the value in "local_date" is right or not.  I agree with @mathguy, and this is a question I need to talk to developer.